# Running a spearman test with a few columns of values in a csv that have #DIV!. It works! But is it supposed to?

Tags: r, correlation

Everything is running fine, but I'm checking to make sure that non-numeric values don't totally screw up the test. I turned the variables into numeric using as.numeric and it returned "introduced by coercion" - but it worked!

I'm running this line of code with a file of 2020 Presidential election data by county and Unemployment data.

cor.test(Unemployment2020, PercentD2020, method = 'spearman', exact = FALSE).

Does the "exact = FALSE" piece make it unnecessary for there to be the same number of numeric values for each variable?

Comment: Please show your data before turning in numeric, then we could help. `exact = FALSE` has nothing to do with same number of numeric.... etc. `exact` is
a logical indicating whether an exact p-value should be computed. Used for Kendall's tau and Spearman's rho. See ‘Details’ for the meaning of NULL (the default). See ?cor.test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `exact = FALSE`.

Since `cor.test` is an S3 generic, when you pass two numeric vectors to it, you will invoke the `stats:::cor.test.default` method. Reviewing the source code of this function, you will see that it silently drops the `NA` values in lines 10 to 13 of the function body:

```r
    OK <- complete.cases(x, y)
    x <- x[OK]
    y <- y[OK]
    n <- length(x)
```

The `complete.cases(x, y)` here will drop `NA` values from both vectors, so that only matching entries where neither are `NA` will be considered.

We can see this in action with the following example. Suppose we have an x and a y vector and want to run `cor.test`, but each has an `NA` value at a different point:

```r
x <- c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(1.1, 1.9, 7, 3.3, 4.5, NA)

cor.test(x, y)
#> 
#>  Pearson's product-moment correlation
#> 
#> data:  x and y
#> t = 13.671, df = 2, p-value = 0.005308
#> alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.7634907 0.9998944
#> sample estimates:
#>       cor 
#> 0.9946918
```

We should get the same result if we drop the third entry from each vector (since `x` has an `NA` there) and drop the 6th entry where `y` has an `NA`:

```r
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y <- c(1.1, 1.9, 3.3, 4.5)

cor.test(x, y)
#> 
#>  Pearson's product-moment correlation
#> 
#> data:  x and y
#> t = 13.671, df = 2, p-value = 0.005308
#> alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.7634907 0.9998944
#> sample estimates:
#>       cor 
#> 0.9946918
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>